# Browser view content collapse , When window get minimized?

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, user-interface

My application will looks good if `browser window` is `fully maximized`. And content get `collapsed` when I `minimized` the `browser window` .

I don't need the content to be collapsed. I have given the `div` which looks like `textarea` to display the message  in `%` only.

My Jsp will be ,

```
<div style="padding-left: 16px;" id="messageLayout">
    <div id="messageDisplayArea" > 

    </div>
</div>
```

My `jquery` will be , when I clicked the `send button` ,

```
function send(){
    name = $("#name").val();
    message = $("#message").val();
    var time = "Time";

    var user = "<div id='user' class='fontStyle'>"+name+"</div>";
    var msg = "<div id='msg'  class='fontStyle'>"+message+"</div>";
    var timeStamp = "<div id='time'  class='fontStyle'>"+time+"</div>";

    var row = "<div id='msgSet' >"+ user + msg + timeStamp +"</div>";

    $("#messageDisplayArea").append(row);
}
```

My `CSS` will be ,

```
#messageDisplayArea {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border-color: #6495ED;
    white-space: normal;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: white;
}

#user {
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    color: red;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#msg {
    width: 79%;
    color: green;
    float: left;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#time {
    width: 10%;
    float:left;
    color: gray;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#msgSet {
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: Can You use jsfiddle.net, to give us code of Your site?

Comment: I updated my content.Kindly check it now .

Comment: What about some more HTML? Can You give `#messageDisplayArea` already filled with content?

Comment: There is no more code in `#messageDisplayArea` div. All I did in `Jquery` to  append the data dynamically when I clicked the button.

Answer (score 0):

try removing your `word-wrap: break-word`